# Batch For Loop Treating Space-delineated Input as Single Token

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, user-input

I'm working on a batch script that is suppose to prompt the user for a list of projects, and then process each of those projects in turn.  My thought was that this could be done with a for loop, but it's not working.  For some reason it's treating the entire string entered by the user (`CanalyzerIF CanoeIF CometIF`) as a single token.

```
echo Enter the names of the projects, deliniating each with a space:
set /P PROJECT_LIST=
echo.
echo DEBUG: PROJECT_LIST is %PROJECT_LIST%
echo These are the projects you specified:
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ("%PROJECT_LIST%") do (
  echo   %%i
)
```

My script output looks like this...

```
DEBUG: PROJECT_LIST is CanalyzerIF CanoeIF CometIF
These are the projects you specified:
  CanalyzerIF CanoeIF CometIF
```

...when what I expect/want to see is this:

```
DEBUG: PROJECT_LIST is CanalyzerIF CanoeIF CometIF
These are the projects you specified:
  CanalyzerIF
  CanoeIF
  CometIF
```

It doesn't seem to matter if I use percent signs (`%`) or exclamation marks (`!`) to wrap `PROJECT_LIST`.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with (plain `FOR` can be used for itration):

```
echo Enter the names of the projects, deliniating each with a space:
set /P "PROJECT_LIST="
echo.
echo DEBUG: PROJECT_LIST is %PROJECT_LIST%
echo These are the projects you specified:
for   %%i in (%PROJECT_LIST%) do (
  echo   %%i
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @npocmaka's perfect solution of the problem using `for` without `/F`, I want to provide a solution with the `/F` option, mainly for demonstration purpose.

First let's take a look at `for /F` without option string, so using default options, which are like `"tokens=1 delims= _"` (`_` stands for a tab here). This means to take the first space- or tab-separated token and assign it to a given variable like `%%i` (that is, the first project in your list) and to ignore the rest.
To get multiple items, you need to specify exactly which ones you want to extract. For instance, to get tokens 2,3,4 & 6, state `"tokens=2-4,6"`.
The first of these tokens is assigned to the given variable `%%i`, the other ones to `%%j`, `%%k`, `%%l` (which constitute implicitly defined variables).
The special token `*` means to pass *all* remaining tokens to a single variable, or, in other words, to treat them as a single token (for example, `"tokens=1,*"` passes the first token to `%%i` and all the rest to `%%j`).

Understanding all this leads us to the main problem using `for /F`: you need to know how many tokens are available. But for this application, we don't know that.

The following uses option string `"tokens=1,*"` to extract the first token and all the rest; there is a kind of while-loop wrapped around (composed by `if` and `goto`) that is intended to reprocess all the rest until nothing is available any more (herein I explicitly defined the space to be the only acceptable delimiter):

```
echo Enter the names of the projects, deliniating each with a space:
set /P PROJECT_LIST=
echo.
echo DEBUG: PROJECT_LIST is %PROJECT_LIST%
echo These are the projects you specified:
set PROJECT_TEMP=%PROJECT_LIST%
:LOOP
if not defined PROJECT_TEMP goto :NEXT
for /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%i in ("%PROJECT_TEMP%") do (
  echo.  %%i
  set PROJECT_TEMP=%%j
)
goto :LOOP
:NEXT
```

So the main problem in the original code is the option string `"tokens=*"`, which defines to pass *all* tokens to the variable `%%i`.

Type `for /?` for more details on all this.